# 1inch aggregation protocol v4 - basic example of swap

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, 1inch-dex-aggregator

I'm trying to figure out how I can use **1inch** AggregationRouterV4 as a smart contract and not as an API.

I have experience with ethers , but I can't find any example and tests on how to work with a smart contract and the swap function.

I found implementations for old one with:

```
function swap(
        IERC20 fromToken,
        IERC20 toToken,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 minReturn,
        uint256[] memory distribution,
        uint256 disableFlags
 ) public payable;
```

But not for the new version:

```
function swap(
  contract IAggregationExecutor caller,
  struct AggregationRouterV4.SwapDescription desc,
  bytes data
) external returns (uint256 returnAmount, uint256 gasLeft)
```

Can someone show an example of a simple exchange of any token using ethers/web3 and AggregationRouterV4 ?

Comment: Did you find any example of how to generate the ` bytes data` ?

Comment: I guess we can't have an answer to this question since AggregationExecutor is closed-source